# Youtube movie not loading

Tags: html, flash, youtube

Why my video is not loading?
I get message "Movie not loaded".
This is code.

```
<div id="cel_2" class="youtube"><object width="600" height="600">
           <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyy44xBlI44"></param>
           <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
           <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>

           <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
           <embed
              src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyy44xBlI44"
              type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
              allowscriptaccess="always"
              allowfullscreen="true"
              wmode = "transparent"
              width="600"
              height="600">
           </embed>
        </object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `src` does not mean `swf` source but iframe source, your script will never work try using the given iframe, like the anwser of @Art Williams

Answer (score 2):

Your better off using youtube's embed code they provide you under the share option.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yyy44xBlI44" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

See if that works.